# How to write compareTo for an instance member?

Tags: java, instance-variables

```
public class Ch3Ex2 {
static class Node {
    Node(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    Object value; // Comparator for this field required
    Node next;
}


static class Stack {
    Node Top;
    Node Min;
    void push(Object value) {
        Node node = new Node(value);
        if(Top == null) {
            Min = node;
        } else {
            Min = (Min.value < node.value) ? Min : node;  // Comparator Needed to be used here
        }
        node.next = Top;
        Top = node; 
    }
```

Comment: What's the question?  What have you tried?

Comment: Do we know the run time type of the object referenced by `value`?

Comment: Actually i need to compare 2 Node Objects based on their values and i want to Implement Comparator for the instance member 'value'. I know that i could implement one for class Node but thats not what i want. I want to implement Comparator for 'value'. Is it possible ?

Comment: Lets assume that we have string at run time for the Object type for value.

Comment: The `String` class already implements `Comparable<String>`.

Comment: Yes but code wont compile because at Compile time my Stack class will not know that i am going to put string in value.

Comment: I think that copairing Nodes is the Logically correct way to solve the issue. Thanks a lot all for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to declare your `Node` class like:

```
class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    T value;
    Node next;
    Node(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Then your `Stack` would look like:

```
class Stack<T extends Comparable<T> {
    Node<T> Top;
    Node<T> Min;
    void push(T value) {
        Node<T> node = new Node<T>(value);
        if(Top == null) {
            Min = node;
        } else {
            Min = Min.value.compareTo(node.value) < 0 ? Min : node;
        }
        node.next = Top;
        Top = node; 
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I think what you are actually asking for is something like:

```
class Node<T> {
    T value;
    Node next;
    Node(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

class Stack<T> {
    Node<T> Top;
    Node<T> Min;
    final Comparator<T> valueComparer;
    public Stack(Comparator<T> valueComparer) { this.valueComparer = valueComparer; }
    void push(T value) {
        Node<T> node = new Node<T>(value);
        if(Top == null) {
            Min = node;
        } else {
            Min = valueComparer.compare(Min.value, node.value) < 0 ? Min : node;
        }
        node.next = Top;
        Top = node; 
    }
}
```

This means your value class does not need to implement `Comparable`, as long as the class constructing the `Stack` object knows how to compare the values by passing in a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Comment: I was thinking in direction of coming up with a way to implement Compartor only for an instance member 'value'. Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes,you can do that.I have edited my answer and shared a link please refer that.It may help you.

Comment: You can have `Node` implement `Comparable<Node>` if you want and the `compareTo` method would only inspect `value`.  However, you still need to know *how* to compare `value`.  If it's *only* typed as an object, you can only use the methods defined on `Object` to compare it, which probably doesn't do what you want.  An alternative to my answer would be to define your own interface that 'value' will implement that exposes methods you can use to compare it with.

Comment: If i implements Comparable for Node than i could compare 2 Node objects the way i want. What if i just want a Comparable for 'value'. For that i would require to implement Comparable in Object class. How to define that so that only the 'value' is affected?

Comment: I could override Object class method defining my own copy of Object class but thats not the correct way. Is there some way of doing this using an anonymous class ?

Comment: SimonC I have not yet tested the code but seems the solution seems good !!!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but try this,

Have the class implement the `Comparable interface`, which gives the `compareTo` method. You can then use the value of the number (-1 for less, 1 for more, 0 for equals) in your if statements.

If you want to put these objects in lists (say, for sorting) you should also @Override the .equals method.

For example :

```
import java.util.Comparable;

public class BlockOffset implements Comparable<BlockOffset>
{
   private int blockNumber;
   private int offset;

   @Override
   public int compareTo(BlockOffset instance2) {
   if (this.blockNumber < instance2.blockNumber) return -1;
   if (this.blockNumber > instance2.blockNumber) return 1;
   if (this.offset < instance2.offset) return -1;
   if (this.offset > instance2.offset) return 1;

   return 0;
 }   
}
```

For more details have a look at [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_comparator.htm) link.

Answer (score 0):

The only logical way i could see is to implement Comparable for my Node class. Implementing a comparing protocol for only 'value' instance member seems illogical.